# how to set a usage location to a user in PowerShell using Microsoft-Graph

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, powershell-2.0

need a mggraph command-let that helps me to set a usage location to an existing user

I tried this command

```
$user=get-mguser -userid f75bff42-f7bf-426a-862c-1771ea379b72
$user.usagelocation="IN"
set-mguser -userid f75bff42-f7bf-426a-862c-1771ea379b72 -usagelocation $user.location
```

**-I tried this because we used to do the same in MSOnline**

by using this I get an error showing that the command `set-mguser` is not recognized:

> set-mguser : The term 'set-mguser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> At line:1 char:1
> set-mguser -userid f75bff42-f7bf-426a-862c-1771ea379b72 -usagelocatio ...
>
> - 
>
> CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (set-mguser:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Hello welcome to the forum. You aren’t using powershell 2.0 to connect to ms graph, please remove unneeded tags. Also, the error tells you exactly what the problem is, your system/session doesn’t have that command. You need to install the module that contains the command.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Set-MgUser` cmdlet in `Microsoft.Graph.Users` submodule.

You need to use `Update-MgUser` cmdlet.

```
$userId = 'f75bff42-f7bf-426a-862c-1771ea379b72'
$usageLocation = 'IN'

Update-MgUser -UserId $userId -Usagelocation $usageLocation
```

Documentation:

[Microsoft.Graph.Users cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users/?view=graph-powershell-1.0)

[Update-MgUser](https://Update-MgUser)